# Создание виртуального хоста linux

Tags: linux, apache2, linux-mint, virtual-hosts

Доброго времени суток. Решил пополнить ряды линуксоидов. В общем, задача поставить апач и настроить виртуальный хост. Все вроде просто, но есть одна проблема - мой хост почему то указывает на дефолтную папку, подсказали что дело в ссылке, но я не могу понять что неправильно, сайт в папке `siteme`, это файл `site.me.conf` из apache `sites-available`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@siteme.com
    ServerName site.me
    ServerAlias www.site.me
    DocumentRoot /var/www/siteme/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

В `sites-enabled` есть ссылка на этот файл с таким же названием, пробовал удалять и снова создавать с помощью `a2ensite`. В `etc/hosts`

```
127.0.1.1 localhost site.me
```

В общем, помогите виндузятнику.

Comment: 1. другие файлы или ссылки в каталоге `sites-enabled` есть? 2. программу перезапускали после внесения изменений в конфигурацию? 3. каким именно образом программу устанавливали?

Comment: 1. Других файлов нет. 2.Да делал `setvice apache2 reload` 3. Если вы про апач, то `sudo apt-get install apache2`

Comment: Вроде, всё верно. А в чём выражается то, что "хост указывает на дефолтную папку"? И как Вы обращаетесь к хосту (что в адресной строке браузера)?

Comment: Адресная строка http://site.me, когда я захожу по этому адресу вижу дерево папок из var/www/